# Mention the member in private message | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am working on a small discord robot that I code in javascript and I cannot mention the user in a private message.

I get `<@899999999959067648>`:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.send(`Hi ${member} !`);
});
```

How to do it?

EDIT : it actually works, but not for embed messages ...

Thank you.

Comment: What DJS version are you on?

Comment: I use Discord.js V12

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.send(`Hi <@${member.user.id}> !`);
});
```

Comment: Hi, it actually works, but not for embed messages ...